# How to implement PNPOLY for CCMenuItem to define touchable areas of a non-rectangle polygon?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, polygon

I'm implementing a touchable rainbow but the concave 'transparent' areas of a upper band is interfering with the lower rainbow bands. I'm hoping to use PNPOLY from (http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) but I don't understand how it is supposed to work. I'm hoping to define the band's touchable area and transparent (non-touchable) area.

Code:

> int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
>   {
>
> int i, j, c = 0;
>
> for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
>
> if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
>
> (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
>
> ```
>  c = !c;
> ```
>
> }
>
> return c;
>
> }

The reference says the boolean expression for a concave entity is A.B.C.(D+E+F). How does this fit into the function?

Comment: Try defining the rainbow as a Box2D object and use the Vertex Helper tool to automatically generate the vertices. That is how I've done it in the past.